# Using one index file in all directories and subdirectories

Tags: apache, webserver, nginx, subdirectory, directory-index

I have an `index.php` file, which processes content of a directory it is located in and renders output to the browser.

The problem is that the directory structure it is supposed to serve is rather complex, with many directories and subdirectories. I don't feel like putting a copy of `index.php` in each and every subdirectory.

I know I can use symlinks on systems that support them but it's still not a human's job to traverse the whole hierarchy and place links to the index file in question if no other is present. Also, not all systems actually support symbolic linking.

Is there a method to tell the webserver (Apache, nginx, ..) that if an index file is not present in a requested directory then it should use the specified `index.php` located elsewhere?

Comment: The `index.php` that you put in your subdirectories should be empty or just an error message, the lack of index.php in your directories can lead to internal errors from the server, or security holes, but you don't need to serve the original index, just leave empty index.php file instead so the directories won't be accessible for example from `yoursite,com/includes/`

Comment: No, it is not about having empty index files. It is about having a kind of virtual copy of the specific index.php file in directories that don't have an index file.

Comment: You mention both Apache and Nginx. So, which is it, Apache _or_ Nginx?

Comment: @knif3r "the lack of index.php in your directories can lead to internal errors from the server, or security holes" - that's nonsense. The only reason some popular CMSs do this is because they are installed by the masses on systems they might have no control over - in order to prevent directory listings (thus exposing the file structure). This can be easily avoided and secured with a few directives in the server config. "just leave empty index.php file instead so the directories won't be accessible" - this would result in a blank page and a misleading 200 OK status. A 403 is preferable.

Comment: @w3dk: It can be either Apache or nginx. Might for example be possible with one and not possible with the other. I can deploy with any of the two.

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you are asking, but cannot figure out why you would need an index.php file in every directory (if typical php application programming practices are followed).

If you have to refer to the root index.php file from every sub-directory, mod_rewrite is the easiest way at the server level. This isn't server agnostic, as you may be asking, but see this article for examples on how to get the server to always refer to the index.php file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595964/redirect-all-traffic-to-index-php-using-mod-rewrite

Comment: "why you would need an index.php file in every directory" - the index file processes the content of the directory it is located in. This is probably not what I would call a typical php application. It is rather a web interface to a specific filesystem structure. If I understand correctly - the rewrite module will actually redirect the request to the root index file, including its directory context? If this is the case then this won't work because the directory context (and content) needs to be from the directories the user traverses.

Comment: @silverdr you should include a .htaccess file in your program including the suggestion by w3dk in that case. I'd much prefer all php logic routed through my root index.php file however, as this is much less error prone than relying on each directory having an index file.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a method to tell the webserver (Apache, nginx, ..) that if an index file is not present in a directory under document root, then it should use the specified `index.php` located elsewhere?

Yes, on Apache you can control this with the `DirectoryIndex` directive in your Apache config (or .htaccess file). For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php /index.php
```

When requesting a filesystem directory, this will serve either `index.php` in that directory, if it exists, otherwise `/index.php` will be served (`index.php` in the document root).

Nginx appears to have a similar directive called simply  `index`.
Reference: https://serverfault.com/a/402949/49157

Comment: This one seems to work such way that the /index.php is in fact served but in the context of the directory it is located in (/). I get correct url (/subdirectory/) but the content comes from /. So it doesn't seem to directly solve the problem. OTOH - since the url remains correct, I might be able to adapt the index.php so that it would use the path information provided in the url.

Comment: Yes, use the URL-path to retrieve the appropriate directory. It's not possible, at the webserver level, to actually load a file in a directory if that file doesn't actually exist in that directory.

Comment: Well, technically there surely is. It could be done the way that the CWD (Current Working Dir) remains as requested and only the missing file is loaded from another location. Similar to what we do when using shell - just refer to the files outside of CWD, without actually changing the directory we work in. But in practice I modified the index.php so that it chdir()s to the requested directory based on the path information given in the URL and that seems to work well enough. Looks a bit ugly with the path processing and urlencode stuff but I guess that's what I have to live with - thanks.